# Forward Slash in the column while using ,isin

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

It looks like I can't filter column where it contains slashes in it.

For example, I have column looking like 'A/B', 'A/B/C', and 'A' or 'B'.

I use the following syntax to filter it out.

```r
a = a.filter(a.column.isin('A/B','A/B/C')
```

it tells me this error:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can you tell me why?

Comment: You're missing a parentheses at the end.

Comment: Good catch. In my real code, I didn't missing it. Probably in this example code, I did miss it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not able to reproduce in **`Spark-2.4`**, may be try by passing list with values included **`['A/B','A/B/C']`**.

**`Example:`**

```
#creating dataframe
df=spark.createDataFrame([('A/B',),('A/B/C',),('A',),('B',)],['a'])

df.show()
#+-----+
#|    a|
#+-----+
#|  A/B|
#|A/B/C|
#|    A|
#|    B|
#+-----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.filter(col("a").isin(['A/B','A/B/C'])).show()

df.filter(col("a").isin('A/B','A/B/C')).show()
#+-----+
#|    a|
#+-----+
#|  A/B|
#|A/B/C|
#+-----+
```